# Excel .XLSM file... Auto save and close?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have several .xlsm files that auto-run a sequence, save and close when opened.  The VBA code I'm using to save and close is...

```
ThisWorkbook.Save
ThisWorkbook.Close
```

The problem I have is that this command closes the workbook, but does not close Excel.  I need it to close Excel also so my batch file will know to start the next .xlsm file in the folder.

Is there different "close" line I could use in my VBA module to completely close Excel?

Thanks

Comment: `Application.Quit` will do it, but you'd want to call it from another instance of Excel.

Comment: I'd suggest PowerShell as an external process that can open the workbook(s), perform the work and close them then exit its own process.

Answer (score 0):

MS Excel is the object `Application` that has a method `Quit` to break the process. So what you can do is just adding the line:

```
Application.Quit
```

into the macro which is supposed to run last. Keep in mind that `Application.Quit` closes only the current MS Excel thread, so if every spreadsheet is running into a new istance of the application, you might want to add this line at the end of every routine:

```
ThisWorkbook.Save 'saves the current workbook
ThisWorkbook.Close 'closes the current workbook
Application.Quit 'quits the current application where you're working.
```